# I using oracle utl_http but returned response does not fit varchar variable(32767) . My response 65000 character. WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Tags: oracle, http

I clob the value of the variables, it still didn't work.

REQUEST_ENV2         VARCHAR2(32767);
RESPONSE_ENV2        VARCHAR2(32767);

RESPONSE_ENV        VARCHAR2(32767);
REQUEST_ENV         VARCHAR2(32767);

ERROR : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: I'd say that you should use a CLOB, then. But, if I understood you correctly (i.e. your first sentence), you already did that but it didn't help. Maybe you should consider posting code that returns the error.

Comment: Yes clob didn't work. :(

Comment: My Solution finally;
I divided response three pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use utl_http.READ_TEXT

It has parameter of "len" - The maximum number of characters of data to read.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-15898E29-77BD-4E1C-9FFF-7FF8F9E568D8